# "Select" statement inside of goroutine with for loop

Tags: for-loop, go, select, goroutine

Could somebody please explain, why if goroutine has endless `for` loop and `select` inside of the loop, a code in the loop is run only one time?

```
package main

import (
    "time"
)

func f1(quit chan bool){
    go func() {
        for {
            println("f1 is working...")
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)

            select{
            case <-quit:
            println("stopping f1")
            break
            }
        }   
    }()
}

func main() {
    quit := make(chan bool)
    f1(quit)
    time.Sleep(4 * time.Second)
}
```

Output:

```
f1 is working...
Program exited.
```

But if "select" is commented out:

```
package main

import (
    "time"
)

func f1(quit chan bool){
    go func() {
        for {
            println("f1 is working...")
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)

            //select{
            //case <-quit:
            //println("stopping f1")
            //break
            //}
        }   
    }()
}

func main() {
    quit := make(chan bool)
    f1(quit)
    time.Sleep(4 * time.Second)
}
```

Output:

```
f1 is working...
f1 is working...
f1 is working...
f1 is working...
f1 is working...
```

https://play.golang.org/p/MxKy2XqQlt8

Comment: @Ullaakut The `break` applies, in this case, to the `select` statement, not the `for` loop, because it's scoped to a `case` statement inside the `select`.  It's also superfluous, as break is implied when the end of a case is reached (an explicit break is not required in Go like it is in C++).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A `select` statement without a `default` case is **blocking** until a read or write in at least one of the `case` statements can be executed. Accordingly, your `select` will block until a read from the `quit` channel is possible (either of a value or the zero value if the channel is closed). The language spec provides a [concrete description](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements) of this behavior, specifically:

> If one or more of the communications [expressed in the `case` statements] can proceed, a single one that can proceed is chosen via a uniform pseudo-random selection. Otherwise, if there is a default case, that case is chosen. If there is no default case, the "select" statement blocks until at least one of the communications can proceed.

## Other code issues

### Caution! `break` applies to the `select` statement

However, even if you did close the `quit` channel to signal shutdown of your program, your implementation would likely not have the desired effect. A (unlabelled) call to `break` will [terminate execution of the inner-most `for`, `select` or `switch` statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Break_statements) within the function. In this case, the `select` statement will break and the `for` loop will run through again. If `quit` was closed, it will run forever until something else stops the program, otherwise it will block again in `select` ([Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/bSVnNGdqPpu))

### Closing `quit` will (probably) not immediately stop the program

As noted [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52356700/select-statement-inside-of-goroutine-with-for-loop/52357443#comment91691377_52357443), the call to `time.Sleep` blocks for a second on each iteration of the loop, so any attempt to stop the program by closing `quit` will be delayed for up to approximately a second before the goroutine checks `quit` and escapes. It is unlikely this sleep period must complete in its entirety before the program stops.

More idiomatic Go would block in the `select` statement on receiving from two channels:

- The `quit` channel
- The channel returned by [`time.After`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#After) – this call is an abstraction around a [`Timer`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer) which sleeps for a period of time and then writes a value to the provided channel.

## Resolution

### Solution with minimal changes

A resolution to fix your immediate issue with minimal changes to your code would be:

- Make the read from `quit` non-blocking by adding a default case to the `select` statement.
- Ensuring the goroutine *actually* returns when the read from `quit` succeeds:

  - Label the `for` loop and use a labelled call to `break`; or
  - `return` from the `f1` function when it is time to quit (preferred)

Depending on your circumstances, you may find it more idiomatic Go to use a [`context.Context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context) to signal termination, and to use a [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) to wait for the goroutine to finish before returning from `main`.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func f1(quit chan bool) {
    go func() {
        for {
            println("f1 is working...")
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)

            select {
            case <-quit:
                fmt.Println("stopping")
                return
            default:
            }
        }
    }()
}

func main() {
    quit := make(chan bool)
    f1(quit)
    time.Sleep(4 * time.Second)
    close(quit)
    time.Sleep(4 * time.Second)
}
```

[Working example](https://play.golang.org/p/aDoSzSzkByp)

(Note: I have added an additional `time.Sleep` call in your `main` method to avoid this returning immediately after the call to `close` and terminating the program.)

### Fixing the sleep blocking issue

To fix the additional issue regarding the blocking sleep preventing immediate quit, move the sleep to a timer in the `select` block. Modifying your `for` loop as per this [playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/fPwiA34Jjnt) from the comments does exactly this:

```golang
for {
    println("f1 is working...")

    select {
    case <-quit:
        println("stopping f1")
        return
    case <-time.After(1 * time.Second):
        // repeats loop
    }
}
```

## Related literature

- [Go-by-example: Non-blocking channel operations](https://gobyexample.com/non-blocking-channel-operations)
- [Dave Cheney's Channel axioms](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/03/19/channel-axioms), specifically the fourth axiom "*A receive from a closed channel returns the zero value immediately*."

Comment: Thank you so much for the such detailed and full answer. The question is a little bit stupid. I had thought to try the empty default:, but it looked weird. Now I see why it isn't.

Comment: @Dimaf another thing is that the `time.Sleep()` call mandates that `quit` is only checked once per second.  A better solution is to `select` over `quit` and a `time.After` call.  Notice that this one can exit on a non-whole-second interval as a result: https://play.golang.org/p/fPwiA34Jjnt

Comment: Thanks @Kaedys, that's a good point. I've edited the answer to add wording to this effect and linked to your playground example.

Comment: @Kaedys, thanks. That looks as the better solution and more idiomatic Go.